# How do I create a new array that removes NaN values?

Tags: matlab

I have a 2D array of size [672 x 8] in which I have several rows where in first and second column I have a value and in the other there is a `NaN` value. There are also other rows which have values in all the columns. I want to create two new arrays so that first array only contains those elements which have `NaN` in them and second in which there is no `NaN` element.

For eg

Row 12:

```
517 2850 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Row 13:

```
652 2037 169 2243 44 2443 -2 2644
```

Comment: do you want to replace the NaNs with zeros? If you get the NaNs out of the array it will change it's size, so there is a good chance it wont be rectangular, which is impossible.

Comment: I do want to replace NaN's with zeros. I want to create two different arrays. The first array will contain for example Row 12 and second array will contain Row 13

Comment: Do not do that, what is the benefit? I can agree on erasing whole NaN rows, but not partial ones.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use [`isnan`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isnan.html) for that.

`TF = isnan(A)` returns an array the same size as matrix `A` containing logical "1" (`true`) where the elements of `A` are `NaN`s, and logical "0" (`false`) where they are not (by the way, for a complex number `z`, `isnan(z)` returns `true` if either the real or imaginary part of `z` is `NaN`, and `false` if both the real and imaginary parts are finite or `Inf`).

Regarding your specific task, to split the original matrix into two, do the following:

```
TF = isnan(A);               %// Determine which elements are NaNs
nan_rows = any(TF, 2);       %// Determine rows that contain NaNs
B1 = A(nan_rows, :);         %// Rows with NaN values
B2_nonans = A(~nan_rows, :); %// Rows without NaN values
```

Comment: You should expand the answer and use `any(TF, 2)` to get the rows that  contain `NaN` values, and then split matrix `A` accordingly.